# social login (nextauth) isn't working with after i add autoprefixer

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, autoprefixer, next-auth

does anyone know what this means, and how i can debug it - i've tried react dev tools - and the states and everything disappear as soon as this message pops up:

```
Server Error
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'id' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Call Stack
<unknown>
file:///home/abda_react/abdn2/node_modules/next-auth/server/lib/providers.js (29:5)
Array.find
<anonymous>
parseProviders
file:///home/abda_react/abdn2/node_modules/next-auth/server/lib/providers.js (28:30)
NextAuthHandler
file:///home/abda_react/abdn2/node_modules/next-auth/server/index.js (88:30)
<unknown>
file:///home/abda_react/abdn2/node_modules/next-auth/server/index.js (251:38)
Object.apiResolver
file:///home/abda_react/abdn2/node_modules/next/dist/server/api-utils.js (101:15)
runMicrotasks
<anonymous>
processTicksAndRejections
node:internal/process/task_queues (96:5)
async DevServer.handleApiRequest
file:///home/abda_react/abdn2/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js (770:9)
async Object.fn
file:///home/abda_react/abdn2/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js (661:37)
```

**my nextauth config file:**

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import EmailProvider from 'next-auth/providers/email';
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

export default NextAuth({
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
    ,EmailProvider({
        server: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER,
        from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
    })
    ,GoogleProvider({
        clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
    // ...add more providers here
    
  ],
  jwt: {
    encryption: true,
  },
  secret: process.env.secret,
  //https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QK24lEvRTI8
  callback: {
    // async jwt(token, account) {
    //   if (account?.accessToken) {
    //     token.accessToken = account.accessToken;
    //   }
    //   return token;
    // },
    // redirect: async (url, _baseUrl) => {
    //   if (url === '/') {
    //     return Promise.resolve('/index');
    //   }
    //   return Promise.resolve('/index');
    // }
  },

  pages: {
    // signIn: '/auth/signin',
    // signOut: '/auth/signout',
    // error: '/auth/error', // Error code passed in query string as ?error=
    // verifyRequest: '/auth/verify-request', // (used for check email message)
    // newUser: '/auth/new-user' // New users will be directed here on first sign in (leave the property out if not of interest)
  }
})

// https://console.cloud.google.com/projectselector2/apis/credentials?authuser=1&pli=1&supportedpurview=project
//All requests to /api/auth/* (signIn, callback, signOut, etc.) will automatically be handled by NextAuth.js.
```

could it be something that's wrongly configured?? but i dont understand why it would work before i installed auto prefixer...

**here is the providers file(i did not write a single code of it):**

```
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports.default = parseProviders;

var _merge = require("../../lib/merge");

function parseProviders(params) {
  const {
    base,
    providerId
  } = params;
  const providers = params.providers.map(({
    options,
    ...rest
  }) => {
    var _userOptions$id, _userOptions$id2;

    const defaultOptions = normalizeProvider(rest);
    const userOptions = normalizeProvider(options);
    return (0, _merge.merge)(defaultOptions, { ...userOptions,
      signinUrl: `${base}/signin/${(_userOptions$id = userOptions === null || userOptions === void 0 ? void 0 : userOptions.id) !== null && _userOptions$id !== void 0 ? _userOptions$id : rest.id}`,
      callbackUrl: `${base}/callback/${(_userOptions$id2 = userOptions === null || userOptions === void 0 ? void 0 : userOptions.id) !== null && _userOptions$id2 !== void 0 ? _userOptions$id2 : rest.id}`
    });
  });
  const provider = providers.find(({
    id
  }) => id === providerId);
  return {
    providers,
    provider
  };
}

function normalizeProvider(provider) {
  var _provider$version;

  if (!provider) return;
  const normalizedProvider = Object.entries(provider).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
    if (["authorization", "token", "userinfo"].includes(key) && typeof value === "string") {
      var _url$searchParams;

      const url = new URL(value);
      acc[key] = {
        url: `${url.origin}${url.pathname}`,
        params: Object.fromEntries((_url$searchParams = url.searchParams) !== null && _url$searchParams !== void 0 ? _url$searchParams : [])
      };
    } else {
      acc[key] = value;
    }

    return acc;
  }, {});

  if (provider.type === "oauth" && !((_provider$version = provider.version) !== null && _provider$version !== void 0 && _provider$version.startsWith("1.")) && !provider.checks) {
    normalizedProvider.checks = ["state"];
  }

  return normalizedProvider;
}
```

so..from what i am guessing, there is no property id in there...but i have no idea why that would change after installing autoprefixer, and also i have no idea how to even consider adding id into this.

**update**

```
changed the providers variable to see maybe it's just google...and it seems i have another issue which i think might be related.  here is the error:

./pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js:3:0
Module not found: Package path ./providers is not exported from package /home/abda_react/abdn2/node_modules/next-auth (see exports field in /home/abda_react/abdn2/node_modules/next-auth/package.json)
  1 | import NextAuth from "next-auth"
  2 | import EmailProvider from 'next-auth/providers/email';
> 3 | import Providers from "next-auth/providers";
  4 | 
  5 | export default NextAuth({
  6 |   // Configure one or more authentication providers

Import trace for requested module:

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
```

here is what i changed:

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import EmailProvider from 'next-auth/providers/email';
import Providers from "next-auth/providers";

export default NextAuth({
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
    // ,EmailProvider({
    //     server: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER,
    //     from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
    // })
    ,Providers.Google({
        clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
    // ...add more providers here
```

**package.json:**

```
  "exports": {
    ".": "./index.js",
    "./jwt": "./jwt/index.js",
    "./react": "./react/index.js",
    "./providers/*": "./providers/*.js"
  },
```

Comment: it seems that ```userOptions.id``` comes up as ```Property 'id' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339)```  but i really am not sure where to start here

Answer (score -1):

ok two things:

1. my email provider credentials were placeholders - that's not good.
2. your signin page needs to be set

for completion, here's what i did:

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

export default NextAuth({
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
        clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
  ]

  ,callback: {
    async jwt(token, account) {
      if (account?.accessToken) {
        token.accessToken = account.accessToken;
      }
      return token;
    },
    redirect: async (url, _baseUrl) => {
      if (url === '/') {
        return Promise.resolve('/index');
      }
      return Promise.resolve('/index');
    }

  ,pages: {
    signIn: '/index',
    signOut: '/index',

  }
  ,debug: false
}
})
```

even though i still cant import all providers - it works, so good enough for now

but again...not sure why it worked before autoprefix...